# Unseting a value in an associative bash array when the key contains a quote

Tags: arrays, bash, escaping, associative-array

I have a bash script that uses filenames as keys in an associative array. Some of the filenames have quotes in them and I can't seem to find any way to unset them.

Here's an example replicating the problem from the terminal:

```
$ declare -A x
$ y="key with spaces"
$ z="key with spaces and ' quote"
$ x[$y]=5   # this works fine
$ x[$z]=44  # as does this
$ echo "${x[$y]}" "${x[$z]}" # no problems here
5 44
$ unset x["$y"] # works
$ unset x["$z"] # does not work
bash: unset: `x[key with spaces and ' quote]': not a valid identifier
$ echo "${x[$y]}" "${x[$z]}" # second key was not deleted
 44
```

The file names processed in my script are arbitrary and need to work regardless of what characters they have in them (within reason, at least needs to work with printable characters.) The unset is used to clear a flag on files with certain properties.

How can I get bash to unset these particular keys when they might contain quote symbols?

Comment: Could you assign an empty string to it instead of unsetting?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately that won't work in my case as the values are also user-supplied and may theoretically be empty. The main workaround I can think of right now is having an additional array like `isunset[$key]=1`

Comment: This seems like a bash bug to me, but I can't find any other references to this particular case.

Comment: In `bash` 4.4 at least, there will be a workaround: `unset x["${z@Q}"]`.

Comment: @chepner what is this `@Q` - is it specifically to fix this case?

Comment: Not this specfically; the new expansion operator is more of a shortcut for `printf '%q'` (see my answer). The problem is that indexed array names occupy this weird middle ground between regular variable name and operator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find this works for me:

```
unset 'x[$z]'
```

This works for other special characters:

```
$ y="key with spaces"
$ v="\$ ' \" @ # * & \`"
$ x[$y]=5
$ x[$v]=10
$ echo ${x[*]}
5 10
$ unset 'x[$v]'
$ echo ${x[*]}
5
```

Comment: Nice. `unset` appears to do some amount of expansion with its argument. I'm pretty sure this isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: I assume, the main reason for bash allowing this quoted argument for `unset` is the ambiguity of square brackets. If it happens that you have a file called `xk` in the same directory, then `unset x[$y]` could expand to `unset xk`. If it doesn't match a file, it doesn't expand the brackets. That's unreliable. Since we cannot write `unset ${x[$z]}`, the only option is `unset 'x[$z]'` I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This is the case where single quotes around associative array key work as well so this should work:

```
$> declare -p x
declare -A x='(["key with spaces and '\'' quote"]="44" )'

$> unset x['$z']

$> declare -p x
declare -A x='()'
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is working, thanks. It does seem really strange though, what if you wanted to have a key with a `$` in it?

Comment: I had tested this with `z="key with spaces, \$ and ' quote "` as well and `unset x['$z']` still works fine.

Comment: I meant something like if you had `declare -A x='([\$z]="5")'` and wanted to unset it with `unset x['$z']`, but that gave an error so I see that you have to add another slash to the `$` when you unset like `unset x['\$z']`

Comment: I prefer: `declare -A x='([$z]="5" )'` and then same `unset x['$z']` works.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bug (at the very least, it is inconvenient). Until a fix is available, you can work around this by getting a shell-quoted version of `$z` with

```
$ unset x["$(printf '%q' "$z")"]
```

In `bash` 4.4, this can more briefly be written as

```
$ unset x["${z@Q}"]
```